# excel sheet automation that contains a dependent dropdown list using python(If possible Pandas otherwise any lib is ok)

Tags: python, excel, automation, drop-down-menu

An excel workbook in XSLB format named "master excel" that contains many worksheet like "master sheet ","sheet1","sheet2" etc. "Master sheet" contains a dependent drop down list in cell A2(lets) which contain 96 name  and this dependent drop down list source is column P (P2 to P96 row) of Appendix 1 sheet i.e P column of sheet 1 sheet contains all 96  name in row 0 to row 98 .Also "master sheet" sheet contains so many data   and 6 parameter are calculated from these data for each 96 name and with the arrival of each month data these parameter is updated in excel sheet as formula set in excel sheet(I don;t have to do any calculation for parameter). I have to create  a new excel sheet using python(If possible using pandas but if any simpler ways is available than that is also fine) that  will contain 4 column named :- parameter name,name,months name up to which I have data, parameter value. First ,domain should be Fetched from sheet1 sheet and so that drop down list in Al cell of Domain Details sheet have that domain name and for that domain all 6 parameter data will be fetched from domain expense sheet and once it;s done for one domain then it will select next domain and will fetch  parameter data for next domain and so on.

"Master Sheet" sheet example format:-

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J | K | L | M | - | - | Z | AA | AB | AC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | YTD |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | cell 2 |
| 2 | Name in dropdown list as A,B,C etc that is coming from column P of sheet1 sheet |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | Parameter 3 name | Parameter 3 Value |  |  |  |  | cell 4 |
| 3 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | Parameter 1 name | Parameter 1 Value | Parameter 4 name | Parameter 5 name |  |  |  |  |  |
| 4 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | Parameter 2 name | Parameter 2 Value | Parameter 4 Value | Parameter 5 Value |  |  |  |  |  |
| 5 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 6 | YY |  | YTD |  | YTD | - | - | - | - | - | YTD | YTD | YTD | YTD |  |  |  |  |  |
| 7 | pp |  | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 5 | 6 | 11 | 24 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 8 | QQ |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Sheet1 sheet example:-

|  | A | B | ----- | P | Q | R |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2 |  |  |  | A |  |  |
| 3 |  |  |  | B |  |  |
| 4 |  |  |  | C |  |  |
| 5 |  |  |  | D |  |  |
| 6 |  |  |  | E |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 96 |  |  |  | xxx |  |  |

output excel sheet  format example:-

| Parameter name | Domain name | Month | Parameter value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Parameter 1 | A | YTD | Paramerte 1 Value |
| Parameter 2 | A | YTD | Paramerte 2 Value |
| Parameter 3 | A | YTD | Paramerte 3 Value |
| Parameter 4 | A | YTD | Paramerte 4 Value |
| Parameter 5 | A | YTD | Paramerte 5 Value |
| Parameter 1 | B | YTD | Paramerte 1 Value |
| Parameter 2 | B | YTD | Paramerte 2 Value |
| Parameter 3 | B | YTD | Paramerte 3 Value |
| Parameter 4 | B | YTD | Paramerte 4 Value |

I am unable to iterate through the dropdown list.I generated excel sheet for one name only that too in value formatting is coming as float not the exact integer that is present in excel sheet.Also date present in 6th row i.e march-2023 is coming as unix epoch like 44136.

Comment: what have you tried so far ?
the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: how to ask a good question:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask